# How does Rx subscribe method preserve context without passing it

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am using Rx with Angular2, and using the Subscribe method, the call backs of the method preserve context of the component (or class) that called it, without passing any reference to it. My question is how do they do that? What is the Javascript trick that makes it possible?

Code snippet:

```
this._userService.SignUpUser(this.model).subscribe(
     user => {
       this.newuser = user; // this, is actually same as the calling "this"? How does this work?      
       },
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error  
);
```

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, I have been searching for three hours, I had no idea the answer lied in arrow functions, so I really advice against marking it as duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the use of an arrow function that provides lexical this keyword. In this case, `this` doesn't correspond to the instance that executes the function but the instance where the function is defined.

It's not related to Rx at all.

See this link for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: And Thierry wins this time!

Comment: silly question it sounds now doesn't it? just wasted hours of my time (search Rx up and down) and the answer belongs to ... ES!

Answer (score 3):

It is because of `=>` instead of `function()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions